# DRY - how to exchange this if-statement into less complex

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dry

Let assume that we have those six variables: `a,b,c,x,y,z`.
Is there a better way to write this if statement which is not so hard-reading?

```
if (((!a && !x) || a === x) && ((!b && !y) || b === y) && ((!c && !z) || c === z))
```

Now let those variables be much longer and this code is going to be more complicated and less readable.

Comment: `!a && !b  <=> !(a||b)` if this makes it easier. I always find it easier to have as few negations as possible in my controll structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding the function approach. The comparison function could be used as a callback inside array's [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method. To not pass the array as a function argument, I'll use `call()` on `arguments`.

```
function compare() {
  return Array.prototype.every.call(arguments, function (e) {
    return !e[0] && !e[1] || e[0] === e[1];
  });
}

if (compare([a, x], [b, y], [c, z])) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: +1, very good approach. ) Then again, descriptive name won't hurt.

Comment: You don't need to create a new array, you can simply call `Array.prototype.every.call(arguments, function ...)`

Comment: that answer seems to be more universal, so I accept it as the best one (and of course up vote)

Comment: @Tibos or even simpler: use `arguments` as a second argument of `every()`.

Comment: @Pavlo I am not sure that works. The second argument of every is passed to the callback as this, but `every` doesn't act on it as far as i can tell.

Comment: @Tibos have just tested it and you are right. What's the reason behind the second argument of `every()` then?

Comment: It saves creating a new function with bind usually. You can find it in many situations where you should provide a callback.

Answer (score 5):

One obvious approach is to functionize the code that's repeated:

```
function checkVars(a, b) {
  return !a && !b  ||  a === b;
}

// ...
if (checkVars(a, x) && checkVars(b, y) && checkVars (c, z)) {
// ...
}
```

As quite correctly mentioned, you should give this function a descriptive name, showing what it really does. Apparently, it checks whether or not given variables are falsy OR whether they are identical, so one obvious choice is `falsyOrIdentical`. Then your `if` statement will become really self-commenting:

```
if (falsyOrIdentical(a, x) 
 && falsyOrIdentical(b, y) 
 && falsyOrIdentical(c, z)) {

 // here goes the code
}
```

If there's more variables to check, Pavlo's approach (a single function using `slice.call(arguments)` trick to turn all the vars into an Array, then applying this function until it fails to each element of this Array with `every` method) is the best. But then again, I really wonder shouldn't all these variables actually be a part of a collection - so you'll be able to go with `every` right away.

Comment: Remember to name the function something descriptive, if possible.

Comment: and what if I have more than 6 variables to check? Is there some option to not write i.e. 10 times `falsyOrIdentical`?

Comment: Well, this strongly suggests you should actually work with a collection (Array or Object), not with just a bunch of variables. In this case Array.every looks like a very straightforward solution for this job.

Comment: `function checkAll() {  
  for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i+=2) {
    if (!checkVars(arguments[i], arguments[i+1]))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}`   Usage: `if (checkAll(a,x,b,y,c,z)) { /* your code */ }`

Comment: @Tibos looks more like an answer.

Comment: @Pavlo it's a reply to codename's request to make this answer  adapt better to more variables. Anyway, i like your approach better.

Comment: @raina77ow up vote from me for a good approach, but I'll choose Pavlo answer, 'cause it seems to be more DRY and universal one...

Answer (score 0):

You should use boolean variables to easier comparision.
Example:
!a && !x could be converted into something like

```
var aAndBeIsNotTrue = !a && !x
var bAndYIsNotTrue = !b && !y
```

And if statement would look like

```
if(aAndBIsNotTrue || a === x) && (bAndYIsNotTrue || b === y)
```

I think you get the point. You can also great new methods with readable names and put boolean logic inside those methods. These can be also unit tested nicely.

Clean Code book contains nice examples about using boolean variables to ease up complicated if statements.

Answer (score -1):

Hi We can use if else ladder to solve the problem :
Here i am using a function CheckCondition() with return value as bool.

```
CheckCondition()
  {
if((!a&&!x)||a==x)
{
if((!b&&!y)||b==y)
{
if((!c&&!z)||c==z)
{
return true;
}
else return false;
}
else return false;
}
else return false;
}
```

The if condition can also be break down into further if else ladder.

Comment: and with 20 variables this function will take 100 code lines - this isn't DRY